# How to insert wide result set from stored procedure into a temporary table or table variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I'm attempting to save the output of a stored procedure into a temporary table or a table variable using various methods I've found.

I've tried declaring a temp table and then doing:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable EXEC storedprocedurename
```

I'm running into an issue, because the stored procedure has around 550 columns in a result set. I cannot create a temp table that wide, because the maximum row size exceeds 8060 bytes.

Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to edit the stored procedure, but I only really need access to about 200 of these columns.  Is there any way to grab only the columns that I want  and stick them in a table variable or temp table to bypass the size issue or am I stuck sticking the entire row of results in a table?

I've also looked into `OPENROWSET`, but the SQL sever I'm using does not allow ADHOC Queries to be enabled, and will not do so. I'm out of ideas at this point as the only thing I know to do is make a clone of the stored procedure and remove around 1/2 the columns I don't need, but then this could be a maintenance issue if the source stored procedure ever changes and I don't know about it.

Comment: 550 columns?! What are you doing with the 200 columns you're returning? - Maybe there's a better solution outside of the SQL and in your application layer that would let you select a smaller subset of the columns?

Comment: I agree. However, the request / task I was given is to make these 200 columns available for reporting. I am executing the stored procedure against many rows in the database to build a reporting table that can be used to query additional details in the event that more research is needed as a result of a crystal report run that uses the same stored procedure.

I agree there are better ways to do it, but based on the ask I'm limited on what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx)? I do not believe it has the same requirements as `OPENROWSET`. You would create a "loopback" Linked Server and use that in the call to `OPENQUERY`. There are some restrictions on `OPENQUERY`, though, in that it does not like Dynamic SQL or anything else that is a restriction of [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx), which it uses internally.

```sql
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
   @server = N'Loopback',
   @srvproduct = N'',
   @provider = N'SQLNCLI',
   @datasrc = N'<your server name>';
```

Then try:

```sql
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Loopback, N'EXEC sp_who2'); -- this gets an error

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Loopback, N'EXEC sp_who'); -- this works
```

---

If `OPENQUERY` is not an option, then this can still be done without much difficulty via SQLCLR. You have two main options:

1. **SQLCLR Stored Procedure:** This is the easier method as there are no restrictions related to what your existing Stored Procedure is doing (i.e. Dynamic SQL, side-effecting functions, DML, `SET` statements, etc). You can use the internal Context Connection (i.e. attach to the same Session that you are already in, and this works while the Assembly is marked as `SAFE` ), execute the Stored Procedure, and cycle through the results with a `SqlDataReader`, sending each row back to the caller as it comes in using `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow` (i.e. stream the rows back). You would create a result set structure using `SqlDataRecord` and only create the columns that you want. You then set each of those columns from the SqlDataReader and it won't matter that the SqlDataReader had many columns that were never accessed.
2. **SQLCLR Table-Valued Function:** This method has the benefit of actually being able to issue a `SELECT` against the operation so that you can add a `WHERE` condition, etc. You would still use a `SqlCommand` / `SqlDataReader`, just like with the SQLCLR Stored Procedure. However, there are some restrictions, just like there are with T-SQL functions.

   - If your current Stored Procedure does not violate any of the rules for creating a T-SQL function (i.e. Dynamic SQL, side-effecting functions, DML, `SET` statements, etc), then you can do read-only executions of Stored Procedures from SQLCLR functions while using the internal Context Connection (i.e. attach to the same Session that you are already in, and this works while the Assembly is marked as `SAFE` ). However, you won't be able to stream the rows back, but instead would need to store them in memory (similar to using a Table Variable in a T-SQL Multi-statement TVF) and release the results at the end of the process.
   - If your current Stored Procedure does violate any of those rules (and doing `SET NOCOUNT ON;` would be a violation as it is a `SET` statement), then you can still do this, but you would need to use a regular / external connection since the Context Connection won't work. This option does have the benefit of being able to stream the rows back using `yield return`, but it also has the two down-sides of: not being a part of the same session (so can't see local temporary tables or `CONTEXT_INFO`), and requiring the Assembly to be marked as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` (but this does *not* require the database to be set to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`: you just sign the Assembly, create an Asymmetric Key in `master` from that DLL / Assembly, create a Login from that Asymmetric Key, and finally GRANT that Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission).

And seeing that the SQL Server that you are hitting does not allow `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries`, if a DBA were to say that SQLCLR also cannot be enabled due to "security" risks, then please direct their attention to a series that I am writing about SQLCLR on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration is required to view content on that site). In the first 4 articles I show, through several examples, exactly how secure SQLCLR is, especially when Assemblies are marked as `SAFE` (which covers 2 of the 3 options noted above).

Comment: Thank you for this information. Based on your comments, I've done some research and it appears that SQLCLR is a function that requires the use of an external app with the .NET framework and cannot be done with just the use of SQL server itself (being called by a SQL Server Agent job), correct?

Comment: @sallou SQLCLR is .NET that is loaded into SQL Server (sits inside of `sys.assemblies`). SQLCLR is the framework that allows for doing .NET code (with limitations) within SQL Server and not externally. You can create Stored Procedures, Functions, Types, Aggregates, and Triggers. Please see the series of articles that I linked to in the answer for a lot more detail on what it is, can do, and can't do. Outside of that, have you tried `OPENQUERY` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to insert only some of the columns in `INSERT ... EXEC` statement. It means that temp table should have all 550 columns. But, you can try to avoid inserting all returned data into those columns.

First option. `INSTEAD OF` trigger. I never used one, so I'm not sure if it will work with temp tables. It should work with normal tables. Main idea - intercept `INSERT` operation in the trigger and replace long values that exceed the 8060 bytes limit and which you don't need with `NULLs`.

Second option. For those long `varchar` columns that you don't need define them as `varchar(1)` in the `CREATE` temp table statement. Main idea - truncate long `varchar` values that you don't need to 1 character, hoping that the final row would be less than 8060 bytes. If you try this approach you'll most likely see this error message: `String or binary data would be truncated.` To suppress this error message and to force the server to truncate the data: `SET ansi_warnings OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor for the data to sent to temp table with the limit number of cols till it reach its end. May this affects the performance.